# Fortran dll libraries across different fortran compilers

Tags: cuda, fortran

Can I compile a fortran subroutines that contains CUDA kernels through PGI compiler as DLLs then use them in a fortran program compiled by other fortran compilers (Fortran Powerstation)?

I cannot compile my old fortran program on PGI since it needs MSFLIB provided by Fortran Powerstation, and DFLIB available by PGI does not perform some of the functions I need.

I tried it and it does not work as seen bellow. The obj1.lib is compild using PGI fortran compiler and the prog.f is compiled (failed attempt) on Fortran Powerstation. https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLIjx.png

Comment: Powerstation is an old buggy piece of... Just find some replacement for the routines in MSFLIB, it is not worth the complications. Alas, it is only 32-bit and it is 2017!

Comment: Thank you for that info. No one to ask around here!

Comment: I just need to ask quick, if I have a real*8 variable compiled on PGI with 32bit and 64bit pgfortran, what would be the difference on an intel processor that has 64bit capability? I actually prefer 32bit for now.

Comment: 64bit allows using more than 2 GB of memory.

Comment: Edit your question instead of a comment. Don't just show a picture. Describe what you did. **Don't just say "it does not work".** Say what exactly you have tried in steps.

Comment: @VladimirF I guess PGI 32-bit compilers do allow for more than 2GB of memory through -Mlarge_arrays flag e.g. compile with: pgfortran -Mlarge_arrays prog.for ... any other deficiencies? thank you for your quick replies.

Comment: Maybe they do (though I doubt), but will it work in connection with Powerstation? I don't think so.

Comment: I am thinking of getting rid of Powerstation after your advice. I just need to understand if 64-bit executables have definite advantages other than the 2GB ram usage. Thank you @VladimirF ... by the way, which compiler do you recommend for fortran?

Comment: The PGI 32-bit compilers do *not* allow for objects larger than 2GB of memory.  "-Mlarge_arrays" can only be used with the 64-bit compilers and allows for individual dynamically allocated objects to be larger than 2GB.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Fortran is not cross-compiler callable.

What *might* be possible is to expose your PGI-CUDA-Fortran code via the Fortran 2003+ C-binding capability. But you cannot use Fortran specific calling conventions this way (assumed shape arrays, derived data types, etc).

I am not using the PGI compiler so cannot comment more on that.

Comment: There is no Fortran 2003+ C-binding capability in the old Powerstation. It is long abandoned. And if there is some rudimentary implementation sure it is as buggy as the rest of the modern features in it.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it *may* be possible, but wouldn't be easy.

I've added PGI built OpenACC code (albeit it was C code) into a DLL that's callable from binaries built by other compilers.  Hence, it might be possible with CUDA Fortran as well.  The key is to compile without runtime dynamic compilation (-Mcuda=nordc) which requires the binary to be linked with pgfortran.  However without RDC, you wont be able to use module device data declared in external modules or call "device" routines in external modules.  In other words, your device code would need to be contained in a single module.

Pierre is correct that in general you can't mix objects compiled by different Fortran compilers.  However, if your interface is using F77 or C calling conventions as well as not do I/O in the DLL, it may be possible.